# Need to capture a string inside of a json file using the jq command

Tags: json, bash, github, curl, jq

I have spent the last 4 hours combing all over the internet for advice and ideas on how to capture a string of interest so that I can pipe it into a variable inside of a bash script for use later in the script.

I have run out of all ideas on how to do this.

I simply want to use jq to get the following string as it's output when using the following json file as the file input.

I need to capture the string

```json
"browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs10011/ghostpdl-10.01.1.tar.xz"
```

specifically the value part

```json
https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs10011/ghostpdl-10.01.1.tar.xz
```

For those who agree with me that the code I have posted below is rediculous in size please see the following GitHub link that will take you right to the line I want to capture.

[GitHub: Line 171](https://github.com/slyfox1186/script-repo/blob/main/json/github.json#L171)

The only successes I have had besides no output being found are a few commands like

```json
jq '.[].url' github.json
jq '.[3].url' github.json
jq '.[9][]' github.json
```

As is obvious I am stupefied and really need some of you guys advice and good help that comes with posting here.

ANY ideas would make my whole day!

```json
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/96992569",
    "assets_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/96992569/assets",
    "upload_url": "https://uploads.github.com/repos/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/96992569/assets{?name,label}",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/tag/gs10011",
    "id": 96992569,
    "author": {
      "login": "chris-liddell",
      "id": 11627080,
      "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjExNjI3MDgw",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/11627080?v=4",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/chris-liddell",
      "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/followers",
      "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/following{/other_user}",
      "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/gists{/gist_id}",
      "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
      "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/subscriptions",
      "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/orgs",
      "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/repos",
      "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/events{/privacy}",
      "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/received_events",
      "type": "User",
      "site_admin": false
    },
    "node_id": "RE_kwDOAwH6wM4Fx_05",
    "tag_name": "gs10011",
    "target_commitish": "master",
    "name": "Ghostscript/GhostPDL 10.01.1",
    "draft": false,
    "prerelease": false,
    "created_at": "2023-03-27T08:44:15Z",
    "published_at": "2023-03-27T10:02:24Z",
    "assets": [
      {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/assets/101122360",
        "id": 101122360,
        "node_id": "RA_kwDOAwH6wM4GBwE4",
        "name": "ghostpcl-10.01.1-win32.zip",
        "label": null,
        "uploader": {
          "login": "chris-liddell",
          "id": 11627080,
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjExNjI3MDgw",
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/11627080?v=4",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/chris-liddell",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
        },
        "content_type": "application/zip",
        "state": "uploaded",
        "size": 10126052,
        "download_count": 1081,
        "created_at": "2023-03-27T08:51:12Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-03-27T08:51:15Z",
        "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs10011/ghostpcl-10.01.1-win32.zip"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/assets/101122363",
        "id": 101122363,
        "node_id": "RA_kwDOAwH6wM4GBwE7",
        "name": "ghostpcl-10.01.1-win64.zip",
        "label": null,
        "uploader": {
          "login": "chris-liddell",
          "id": 11627080,
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjExNjI3MDgw",
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/11627080?v=4",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/chris-liddell",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
        },
        "content_type": "application/zip",
        "state": "uploaded",
        "size": 10654174,
        "download_count": 2190,
        "created_at": "2023-03-27T08:51:15Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-03-27T08:51:18Z",
        "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs10011/ghostpcl-10.01.1-win64.zip"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/assets/101122291",
        "id": 101122291,
        "node_id": "RA_kwDOAwH6wM4GBwDz",
        "name": "ghostpdl-10.01.1.tar.gz",
        "label": null,
        "uploader": {
          "login": "chris-liddell",
          "id": 11627080,
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjExNjI3MDgw",
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/11627080?v=4",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/chris-liddell",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
        },
        "content_type": "application/gzip",
        "state": "uploaded",
        "size": 96849416,
        "download_count": 2624,
        "created_at": "2023-03-27T08:50:15Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-03-27T08:50:32Z",
        "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs10011/ghostpdl-10.01.1.tar.gz"
      },
      {
        "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/assets/101122309",
        "id": 101122309,
        "node_id": "RA_kwDOAwH6wM4GBwEF",
        "name": "ghostpdl-10.01.1.tar.xz",
        "label": null,
        "uploader": {
          "login": "chris-liddell",
          "id": 11627080,
          "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjExNjI3MDgw",
          "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/11627080?v=4",
          "gravatar_id": "",
          "url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell",
          "html_url": "https://github.com/chris-liddell",
          "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/followers",
          "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/following{/other_user}",
          "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/gists{/gist_id}",
          "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
          "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/subscriptions",
          "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/orgs",
          "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/repos",
          "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/events{/privacy}",
          "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/chris-liddell/received_events",
          "type": "User",
          "site_admin": false
        },
        "content_type": "application/x-xz",
        "state": "uploaded",
        "size": 73020984,
        "download_count": 7698,
        "created_at": "2023-03-27T08:50:32Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-03-27T08:50:49Z",
        "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs10011/ghostpdl-10.01.1.tar.xz"
      }
    ],
    "tarball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/tarball/gs928rc3",
    "zipball_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/zipball/gs928rc3",
    "body": ""
  }
]
```

Comment: You have to traverse the document tree to get there, either by manually specifying the path (try `jq -r '.[0].assets[3].browser_download_url'`), or by programmatically filtering out other possibilities. As there are 4 fields named `"browser_download_url"` in your sample code, you'd need to specify some constraining filters (e.g. the one with the highest version number etc.) if you need help with the programming of such filter.

Comment: You did it. You brilliant person you. Make this an official answer and I will give you the green thumbs up as the accepted choice.

Comment: Counter proposal: Play around with the working snippet (e.g. [here](https://jqplay.org/s/xt1WAztlT9W)), try out some variations, and see what works and what doesn't, especially in the (your) more general case. Then, compose an answer yourself (and accept it if you like), so others can benefit not only from the solution but also from following along your findings.

Answer (score 0):

The desired string is the last produced by:

```
..
| objects
| select(has("browser_download_url"))
| .browser_download_url
```

so in the absence of more detailed requirements, I'll go with wrapping this in last():

```
last( .... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it using `tostream`.

```
[ tostream
| select(.[0][-1] == "browser_download_url" and .[1])
| .[-1] ]
| last
```

Try it on [jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/qGd246H7GFg).